# Организация транзакций в микросервисной архитектуре

Tags: .net, asp.net, api, rest

Добрый день! Есть реализация нескольких api. Подскажите как реализовать выполнение методов различных api в одной транзакции?

Comment: `TransactionScope`?

Comment: @VladD интересно как вы себе это представляете?

Comment: Если эти самые API смотрят на текущую транзакцию — самым прямым образом. Создаёте явный TransactionScope, операции выполняются в нём, вместо того, чтобы неявно создавать свою транзакцию.

Comment: @VladD не совсем понимаю как это должно выглядеть

Answer (score 3):

Вы встретились с новой архитектурой, которая появилась как ответ на естественные ограничения масштабируемости монолитного приложения, и она имеет как свои плюсы (условно-бесконечное масштабирование и способность приложения продолжать работу при физическом отсутствии некоторых компонентов), так и свои минусы. Один из таких минусов - это то, что процессы протекают в неведении друг о друге и не имеют общей синхронизации из коробки (она в большинстве случаев и не нужна - это затормозило бы всю систему, и весь положительный эффект горизонтального масштабирования сошел бы на нет). Поэтому такого понятия как транзакция в распределнной системе просто нет - транзакция требует синхронизацию узлов, а это, в свою очередь, превратит распределенный сервис в обычное монолитное приложение, реплицируемое по нескольким узлам. Поэтому транзакция физически невозможна с сохранением архитектуры.

Классическия транзакция с точки зрения базы данных невозможна еще и потому, что данные находятся на нескольких узлах - в случае, если у вас есть N узлов с базой данных, некоторые данные могут находится только на K < N узлов (где K = фактор репликации). В этом случае транзакцию становится очень сложно поддерживать, потому что о ней должны узнать все узлы (а их легко может быть и тысяча), нужно принимать во внимание узлы, с которыми была потеряна связь, и т.п. Сама архитектура встает на дыбы против таких вещей.

Таким образом, если вы хотите реализовать транзакцию в виде исполнения нескольких действий (или отката тех, которые успели свершиться), вам ничего не остается, кроме как реализовать ее самому. В зависимости от конкретной задачи это может быть как сложный, так и очень сложный процесс, поэтому проще написать конкретную поставленную задачу и разобрать ее.